# Incapable of creating temporary table in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I am beginner to SQL (also using oracle). I am having a problem which I find mind-boggling since what I want to do is so simple.

In short, I want to make a join on two tables from different databases. I do not have admin privileges so I cannot create a view.

I dumped as .csv the table I wanted to join to, and am trying to load it in the other database connection. All my attempts at creating a new table have been met with "insufficient privileges" error.

I have tried

- "Import data"
- CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE
- CREATE TEMPORARY TABLESPACE

How can I create a table or import data when I do not have admin privileges?

edit: I cannot create a view.

solved: I had basically no privileges on my account (not even on my own schema). Talked to the admin and got the right privileges

Comment: If you don't have the privileges to create a table, then you cant. Either ask for more privileges, or do a join without creating an intermediate table.

Comment: The tables I want to join are from different database connections though.

Comment: You don't need "admin" privileges (maybe you mean sys), but you do need create table rights. Ask your DBA to create your own schema that you can control.  And also have them setup a database link so you can query both tables from one DB.

Comment: If you can create a database link, that would be another option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to create a table, you need:

- the CREATE TABLE privilege granted to your user
- quota defined on the tablespace where you want to create the table (or the UNLIMITED TABLESPACE privilege, which gives you unlimited quota on all tablespaces, but using this is bad practice)

If any of the above missing, you get the insufficient privileges error.

PS: to create a view, you dont have to be an admin, you just need the CREATE VIEW privilege granted to your user

Comment: If I cannot create a view, is there any way I can join from the two databases?